# wpf application c# How to minimize/bring to front sub forms

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application is a media player that has a button that launches another window to a certain location and is my webbrowser.  Problem is, once i click my button to launch the browser, my 'hide' button does not hide the browser window :/, from what i researched i need to inherit button click events, take a look at the code:

```
private void button4_ClickWeb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    //opens a web browser if 'Web' is clicked on the WPF Media PLayer
            Window1 f1 = new Window1();
            f1.Show();




    }
```

the ideas i thought would work is create a 'toggle button' like such:

```
  private void button4_ClickWeb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;
        if ((bool)tb.IsChecked)
        {
            f1.Show();
          //or
          f1.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            f1.Hide();
            f1.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        } 

    }
```

this approach failed, and yes i tried variations and moving things around with NO success, i was told that i need to make a class of f1 to inherit button click events but i have no idea how to do that :/ any ideas?

here is how the app looks like:

[image]